# mysql Unknown column variable in the field list

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a procedure which will accept victims and their count.The `victims`
parameter will contain the values like this `'123,321,222'` and I am using a function
call `SPLIT_STR_FUNCTION` to split the text into comma seperated values. Then I 
will insert each value in the database.

here is my procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertPost`( in pmsg text, in pthumbPath text, in ppath text, in puserid bigint, in count int, in victims text) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO posts(path,thumbpath,msg,userid) VALUES(ppath,pthumbpath,pmsg,puserid);


SET @lastpostid = (SELECT postid FROM posts ORDER BY postid DESC LIMIT 1);

SET @startindex=1;

WHILE @startindex <= count DO 
SET @IndividualIDs=convert((select SPLIT_STR_Function(victims, ',', @startindex)),signed); 
SET @startindex=startindex+1;     
INSERT INTO victims(victimid,postid) VALUES(@IndividualIDs,@lastpostid); 

end WHILE; 
END
```

Error:
    **Unknown column startindex in the field list**

**SPLIT_STR_FUNCTION:** (from [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/))

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR_Function`(
x VARCHAR(255),
delim VARCHAR(12),
pos INT
 ) 

 RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
 RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
    LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
    delim, '')
```

Comment: thnx i wasted hours on this silly mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user variable `@startindex` is missing its `@` when you increment it:

```
SET @startindex=startindex+1;
-- Should be:
SET @startindex = @startindex+1;
```